# Find name of the web service in callback handler

Tags: java, web-services, callback, cxf

I have a Custom Callback Handler which implements `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler`. I want to know the name of the web service, request to which has invoked my Custom Callback Handler. I am using Apache CXF web service stack. Can I get the web service name in my Custom Callback Handler?